# AWS: Add Connection to glue job with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, jobs, aws-glue

I want to add connection my glue job using lambda, so I did so:

```
response = glue.create_job(Name="redshift", Role="XXXXXXX",Command={                                
            'Name':'glueetl',                      
            'PythonVersion':'3',       
            'ScriptLocation':path_redshift_job,    
        },ExecutionProperty={'MaxConcurrentRuns':1}, Connections={
        'Connections': ['RedshiftClusterConnection']})
```

But as you see in the image connection no connection is added to the job, what can I do to solve this issue ?

[image: connections image]

Comment: what was the response from glue using the create_job

Comment: could you print the response variable

Comment: hello  @AbdelrahmanMaharek , thank you for you resonse :)  
So, here is the response: 
`{'Name': 'redshift', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '28671bc9-239c-41b8-8464-e7cc68bcfdc7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Wed, 08 Jul 2020 16:00:48 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '19', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '28671bc9-239c-41b8-8464-e7cc68bcfdc7'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}`

Comment: could you run aws glue  get-job --job-name --region <region_name>

Comment: I think the region might not be the same

Comment: I change this in my code and now it's working:
I put the connection in a list `list_connec= ['RedshiftClusterConnection']` and then I passed in the fucntion paramerters 
  `response = glue.create_job(Name="redshift", Role="XXXXXXx",Command={ 'Name':'glueetl', 'PythonVersion':'3','ScriptLocation': "s3://XXXXXX", }, ExecutionProperty={'MaxConcurrentRuns':1}, Connections={'Connections': list_connec},GlueVersion='1.0',MaxRetries=0,DefaultArguments=redshift_default_arguments)`

It did work like this

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: For real, I see no difference between the two but when I tried to pass connections like I've done at the first place it didn't work, but when I created a list and passed it in param it worked. It doesn't make too much sense to me but it worked this way.